# Get External IP in ASP

Tags: php, ip

In `php` I use this to get IP address which returns correctly,

```
<?php
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
echo $ip; 
?>
```

Now how do I go about replicating this in Classic ASP?

Comment: 10 seconds on google (search for *asp get remote ip* ), returns [ASP ServerVariables](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp) - please try to do more research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

```
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr"))%>
```